# Covariation of X and XY

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, covariance

Suppose that a transport company operates $40$ trams and $80$ buses. Every day, independently of each other, each tram breaks down with probability $0.01$, and each bus breaks down with probability $0.02$ (independently of each other and of the trams). Let $X$ be the number of trams breaking down during a day, and $Y$ be the number of buses breaking down on the same day. Calculate the covariance of $X$ and $X · Y$.

My solution:
$$X: n = 40, p = 0.01, M(X) = np = 0.4$$
$$Y: n = 80, p = 0.02, M(Y) = np = 1.6$$
$$M(XY) = M(X)M(Y) = 0.64$$
$$cov(X, XY)=M(XXY) - M(X)M(XY)$$
And I dont know how to calculate $M(XXY)$. Because the idea of $M(XXY) = M(X)M(XY)$ leads to $cov(X,XY) = 0$

Comment: Sorry for Russian designation, here M(X) is expected value, thus M(X) is E[X]

Comment: Can I calculate using following approach: $$E[XXY]=E[X^2]E[Y]=(Var[X]-(E[X])^2)E[Y]=(npq-0.4^2)1.6=0.236*1.6=0.3776$$ Then I can compute covariation

Answer (score 1):

I presume that $M$ in your solution means Expectation.

In this problem, $X\sim \text{Bin}(40, 0.01)$ and $Y\sim \text{Bin}(80, 0.02)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent. In particular
$$
\text{Cov}(X, XY)=EX^2Y-EXEXY
$$
To compute $EX^2Y$ we use the fact that if $X, Y$ are independent then so are $\varphi(X)$ and $\psi (Y)$ where $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are any (measurable) functions. In particular $X^2$ and $Y$ are independent and so
$$
EX^2Y=EX^2EY
$$
which you can compute.